# How to Add IF condition for html tag and in database connection using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi iam doing contact us form for sending emails to multiple users in that i need to add if condition in HTML as well as in database files, because if i select dropdown according to that the columns has to be changed.But if i add the IF condition also it is displaying for all.Here is my code.

contact.php

```
           <form method= "post" action="contactus.php" id="myform">                
                <p>
                <label for="user">User</label>
                <select id="user" name="user">
                                <option value="employee">Employee</option>
                                <option value="company">Company</option>
                                <option value="freelancer">Freelancer</option>
                </select>
                </p> 

            <?php if('selected==company'):?>
                <p>
                <label for="username">Your Name *</label>

                <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Enter your name here" required />

                </p>

                <p>

                <label for="email">Email *</label>

                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Enter E-mail id here" required/>

                </p>

                 <?php endif;?>              

                <p>

                <label for="mobile_no">Phone</label>

                <input id="mobile_no" type="text" name="mobile_no"  placeholder="Enter mobile no. here" />

                </p>

                <p>

                <label for="subject">Subject</label>

                <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" value=""  />

                </p>    

                <p>

                <label for="message">Message</label>

                <textarea id="message"  name="message"   ></textarea>

                </p>

                <p>

               <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>

                </p>
```

Contactus.php

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
    $uname = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];   
    $phone = $_POST['mobile_no'];   
    $message = $_POST['message'];       
    $subject=$_POST['subject'];         
    $sql2 = mysql_query("insert into contact_us(username,email,mobile_no,message,subject) values ('$uname','$email','$phone','$message','$subject')");
    if ($sql2) 
    {
      $to = "email@gmail.com,mail@gmail.com";
         $subject = $_POST['subject'];        
         $message = $_POST['message'];       
         $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message);    
    echo "Message sent successfully...";
         }else {
            echo "Message could not be sent...";
         }
?>
```

Can anyone help me how to add the condition in both contact.php and contactus.php and the data should be inserted into database.it will be very needfull for me.

Comment: On which server are you running the PHP Code . XAMPP or WAMPP  ? It is possible that your directly running it as such without a proper url because of which the browser parses it as HTML itself rather than perceiving it as PHP Code

Comment: Iam using XAMPP server.Url as localhost/project/contact.php

Comment: @Nagu : You should show/hide name and email fields in contact.php via javascript. It cannot be handled by php.

Comment: Can you please help me regarding that it will be thankful

Comment: @Nagu, your english is not clear at all. Please try to explain more clearly what you want to be done

Comment: As I am creating a contact us form in that form i need to display name,email etc if i select the dropdown value as company and if i select employee or freelancer it should show name,email,mobile ,subject fields .This is my requirement

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements, it really isn't hard.

Comment: @Nagu: check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use javascript or jquery for this functionality. I have used `jquery`. Please update your code as below and check :

contact.php

```
<form method="post" action="contactus.php" id="myform">


<p>
        <label for="user">User</label> <select id="user" name="user" onchange="showRequiredOption(this.value);">
            <option value="employee">Employee</option>
            <option value="company">Company</option>
            <option value="freelancer">Freelancer</option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p style="display:none;" id="showName">

        <label for="username">Your Name *</label> <input id="username"
            type="text" name="username" value=""
            placeholder="Enter your name here" />
    </p>
    <p style="display:none;" id="showEmail">

        <label for="email">Email *</label> <input id="email" type="email"
            name="email" value="" placeholder="Enter E-mail id here" />
    </p>

    <p>

        <label for="mobile_no">Phone</label> <input id="mobile_no" type="text"
            name="mobile_no" placeholder="Enter mobile no. here" />
    </p>

    <p>

        <label for="subject">Subject</label> <input id="subject" type="text"
            name="subject" value="" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
        <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </p>
</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showRequiredOption(cval)
{
    if(cval=='company')
    {
        $('#showName').show();
        $('#showEmail').show();
        $('#username').attr('required','required');
        $('#email').attr('required','required');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#showName').hide();
        $('#showEmail').hide();
        $('#username').removeAttr('required');
        $('#email').removeAttr('required');
    }
}
</script>
```

Contactus.php

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
    $uname = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';   
    $phone = $_POST['mobile_no'];   
    $message = $_POST['message'];       
    $subject=$_POST['subject'];  
    if(empty($uname) && empty($email)){
        $sql2 = mysql_query("insert into contact_us(mobile_no,message,subject) values ('$phone','$message','$subject')");
    }else{
       $sql2 = mysql_query("insert into contact_us(username,email,mobile_no,message,subject) values ('$uname','$email','$phone','$message','$subject')");
    }

    if ($sql2) 
    {
         $to = "email@gmail.com,mail@gmail.com";
         $subject = $_POST['subject'];        
         $message = $_POST['message'];       
         $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message);    
    echo "Message sent successfully...";
     }else {
        echo "Message could not be sent...";
     }
?>
```

Comment: @Nagu Great it helped you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript for this functionality You need to write code as below:-

**contact.php**

```
 <form method= "post" action="contactus.php" id="myform">
            <p>
            <label for="user">User</label>
            <!-- Add onchange function myFunction() here -->
            <select id="userd" name="user" onchange="myFunction()">
                         <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="employee">Employee</option>
                        <option value="company">Company</option>
                        <option value="freelancer">Freelancer</option>
            </select>
            </p>


        <!-- Add div here. Show/Hide it based on selected option using javascript -->
        <div id='optional'>
            <p>
            <label for="username">Your Name *</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Enter your name here" required />
            </p>
            <p>
            <label for="email">Email *</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Enter E-mail id here" required/>
            </p>
        </div>  
        <!-- End of the div -->


            <p>
            <label for="mobile_no">Phone</label>
            <input id="mobile_no" type="text" name="mobile_no"  placeholder="Enter mobile no. here" />
            </p>
            <p>
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" value=""  />
            </p>  

            <p>
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea id="message"  name="message"   ></textarea>
            </p>

            <p>
             <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
            </p>

    </form>
```

Add this Js in this file just above `</body>` tag as below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction(){
        var e = document.getElementById("userd");
        var company = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            if(company != 'company'){
            document.getElementById('optional').style.display = 'none';
           }else{
            document.getElementById('optional').style.display = 'block';
           }            
    }          
</script>
```

Your contactus file should be:-

**Contactus.php**

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
    // check username is exist or not in $_POST
    $uname = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
    // check email is exist or not in $_POST
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';   
    $phone = $_POST['mobile_no'];   
    $message = $_POST['message'];       
    $subject=$_POST['subject'];  
    // check $uname and $email is set or not 
    if(empty($uname) && empty($email)){
        $sql2 = mysql_query("insert into contact_us(mobile_no,message,subject) values ('$phone','$message','$subject')");
    }else{
       $sql2 = mysql_query("insert into contact_us(username,email,mobile_no,message,subject) values ('$uname','$email','$phone','$message','$subject')");
    }

    if ($sql2) 
    {
         $to = "email@gmail.com,mail@gmail.com";
         $subject = $_POST['subject'];        
         $message = $_POST['message'];       
         $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message);    
    echo "Message sent successfully...";
     }else {
        echo "Message could not be sent...";
     }
?>
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: it is not working it is displaying the div for all the dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

. PHP is a server side language and so it will render everything and pass it to client so if u need to execute something using php then u need to pass to server and then execute. 
if you want to execute something at client side You need to use JS or JQuery or any other client side language.

[JS FIDDILE EXAMPLE of yours](https://jsfiddle.net/376mv6tg/)

```
<form method= "post" action="contactus.php" id="myform">

            <p>

            <label for="user">User</label>

            <select id="user" name="user">
                            <option value="employee">Employee</option>
                            <option value="company">Company</option>
                            <option value="freelancer">Freelancer</option>
                            </select>

            </p>

<div id='username'>
            <p>

            <label for="username">Your Name *</label>

            <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Enter your name here" required />

            </p>

            <p>

            <label for="email">Email *</label>

            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Enter E-mail id here" required/>

            </p>
            </div>
            <p>

            <label for="mobile_no">Phone</label>

            <input id="mobile_no" type="text" name="mobile_no"  placeholder="Enter mobile no. here" />

            </p>

            <p>

            <label for="subject">Subject</label>

            <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" value=""  />

            </p>    

            <p>

            <label for="message">Message</label>

            <textarea id="message"  name="message"   ></textarea>

            </p>

            <p>

           <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>

            </p>
<script>
        $('select').on('change', function() {
      if(this.value == "company"){
      $("#username").show();
      }else{
      $("#username").hide();
      }
      });
</script>
```